# Python string splitting with more than one separator and non roman characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

I've been asking about it here lately, but I have one more example that I can not deal with.

```
import re

title = "Nad Ziemią / Above Ground – test - filmy i seriale"

if title.find('/') >= 0:
    original_title = (re.split('[-/()]', title)[1])

print(original_title)
```

The result of this will be:

```
Above Ground - test
```

And I need to split another dash to get only the movie title:

```
Above Ground
```

Is it possible to do all in one?

Regards.

Comment: Could not you just do: `title.split('/ ')[1].split(' -')[0]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMPORTANT: The below works as written in Python 3, but for Python 2.7 (or older versions) you will need to deal with the differences in default encoding. See [Unicode HOWTO: Unicode Literals in Python Source Code](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code) to determine what might be needed in your specific situation.

A little trickier than it appears at first because there are non roman characters in your string and the first and second dashes are not actually the same character (first one is an [en dash](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html)). You can actually get the result you are looking for without regex if you first `encode` the string, then split on the en dash code, then split the first result on your forward slash, and then decode the result.

```
title = "Nad Ziemią / Above Ground – test - filmy i seriale"

title.encode().split(b'\xe2\x80\x93')[0].split(b'/')[1].decode()

# OUTPUT
# Above Ground
```

Comment: Well, now I see there are some problems with those chars with Python 2.1.7. Tried to use your solution but got: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0142' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Oh, had to add: import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8'). Now it works fine.

Comment: @serengeti - really important point. Glossed over the python-2.7 tag on your question, which is a real problem in this case. Python 2.7 default encoding is ASCII and before 2.4 default encoding was Latin-1. There are a number of ways to work around this issue and anyone using older versions of Python should read [Unicode HOWTO: Unicode Literals in Python Source Code](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code) to help determine what will work in their specific situation.

Answer (score 2):

Investigating your question further it looks like that character isn't a normal hyphen (it's slightly higher), copy it into your regex expression and you'll see:

```
import re

title = "Nad Ziemią / Above Ground – test - filmy i seriale"

if title.find('/') >= 0:
    original_title = (re.split('[–\-/()]', title)[1])


print(original_title)
```

Bonus points if anyone can work out what the character is.

Comment: Wow, I need to buy new glasses, I am sorry, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With regex you can use the positive loosbehind assertion. Find the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) :)

```
import re

title = "Nad Ziemią / Above Ground – test - filmy i seriale"

if title.find('/') >= 0:
    original_title = re.search('(?<=[-/()])[ \w]+', title)

print(original_title.group(0))
```

Output:

```
Above Ground
```